# Was there an opposition to Arizal?

Tags: history, hashkafah-philosophy, mysticism-kabbalah, arizal

There was a big conflict about the Hashkafa of Rambam.

But it seems that there was nothing to contradict the Arizal, as if everybody agreed with the fact that he learned with Elyahu, and so him being almost indisputable.

Is it true? Was it because the Kabbala was already "too much" popular in order to have real opposition?

Comment: The Rambam didn't claim divine revelation. When you claim that you immediately raise the stakes from regular machloket rishonim to potential outright heresy which makes it harder to have a productive dispute. Look at other claims of 'late' divine revelation and how disputes surrounding it quickly devolve to schisms (eg Mormons)

Comment: This isn't entirely true. Not everyone agreed with the mystical aspect of the Ari. Rabbi Yehuda Aryeh of Modena dedicated a chapter to him in his anti-Kabbalah book Ari Nohem and concluded that though the Ari was probably wise and pious, he certainly was not a mystic miracle-worker with ruach hakodesh.

Comment: [Here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31447&st=&pgnum=107) is the chapter mentioned by @Harel13

Comment: I remember seeing a story (don't remember where) that when the Arizal was learning by the Radvaz in Egypt there was some opposition from local Rabbanim to his teaching Kabbalah. They summoned him to a beis din, at which a strong feeling of pachad came over them, and they left him alone after that. This could just be a legend though.

Comment: First, what do you mean by "it seems", did you ask a couple of rabbis first? Second, contrary to Rambam, Arizal didn't touch the Halacha and basic Jewish theology, he dealt primarily with metaphysics. This wasn't a popular realm, so naturally, there was not much opposition.

Comment: @DoubleAA that's pretty much what seems to me. But isn't it "cheating" a bit ? @ Harel13 I know there was some opposition to the Arizal even to the Zohar, my question is why there was nothing more virulent. I mean, the Rambam just spoke in his own name, but the Arizal claimed (or his talmidim) to speak on behalf of Elyahu Hanavi/

Comment: More like the opposition to Zohar is what there initially was and after great rabbis like the Arizal HaChai and the Ramak recognized the Zohar as being valid then the opposition to Zohar ended.